# Mat-Angular-Stepper como ir para a próxima etapa através do typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando dar o `next` através de uma função.

Vi na [documentação](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) que eles possuem o método `next()`

Porém eu tentei estanciar tanto o `matStepper` quanto o `matStepperHorizontal` no meu `constructor` porém eu recebo:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatFormField -> ChangeDetectorRef]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatFormField ->
>   ChangeDetectorRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!

Não consigo colocar no provider do meu app module esse serviço...

Comment: Coloque seu código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Mostra o que fez.

Comment: Já consegui. adicionei como resposta a minha resolução guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui adicionando a seguinte variável local `#stepper`:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
```

E então no meu formulário, no onSubmit eu passei o stepper como parâmetro:

```
<form (onSubmit)="eventoSubmit(stepper)">
```

E então na minha função eventoSubmit:

```
eventoSubmit(stepper: MatStepper){
   stepper.next()
}
```